# read data from multiple files but would like to write that data into a new text file but file shows up blank

Tags: python, python-3.x

the code reads from multiple text files so far i have it to display on the terminal but i would like to have the info written into a text file but the text file shows up blank and dont know why new to python so still haven't figured out all the commands.

```
directory = 'C:\Assignments\\CPLfiles\*'
test = False
start_text = '^GMWE'

for filename in glob.glob(directory):
    with open(filename) as f:
        with open('file.txt', 'w') as f1:
            for line in f:
                #for x in line:
                    if test is False:
                        if re.search(start_text, line.strip()) is not None:
                            x = line.strip()
                            f1.write(x+ '\n')
                            print(x)
                            break


    test = False
```

Comment: Please change the code so it is compilable for others. Also, when you are creating directory paths, I suggest to checkout: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change the order of opening files to the following.
The problem is that for each file you open to read, you're also re-opening the file to write, whipping it's contents.

Also, due to the break you will write at maximum one line per file due to the break after the write statement.
If the last file that you opened does not have any match with the regular expression, then nothing will exist in the final file.

Hope it makes sense

```
directory = 'C:\Assignments\\CPLfiles\*'
test = False
start_text = '^GMWE'

with open('file.txt', 'w') as f1:
    for filename in glob.glob(directory):
        with open(filename) as f:
            for line in f:
                #for x in line:
                    if test is False:
                        if re.search(start_text, line.strip()) is not None:
                            x = line.strip()
                            f1.write(x+ '\n')
                            print(x)
                            break


    test = False
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the main problem here is that you reopen file.txt for each file in you globbing. Each time opening it in write mode erases the file. If no line match in the last file you will end up with an empty file as a result. So your loop should be inside your `with` that opens this file.

Comment: I had the text file being sent to a different drive instead of my C: it was going to my B: drive I'm such a idiot lolz but thanks it worked